# How do I do a Chrome offline installation?

Tags: google-chrome

How can we install google chrome in ubuntu 11.10 in offline mode ? (Standalone installer for Google Chrome in ubuntu)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install Google Chrome offline by going to the [download page](https://www.google.com/chrome) and download the .deb file that is matching your Linux version (32bit or 64bit).

After download you can open the window of that folder and just double-click the downloaded file.

Alternatively, after saving the file to a local directory you should open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and change to that directory. You should then execute the command:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -i <filename>
```

Where `<filename>` is the name of the downloaded file.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions ! Was able to install in offline mode :)

Comment: The download is based off your user agent, so if you are on another OS, use this download link: https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: I believe this needs to be updated. Going to their website just prompts to download based on your current browser/os. No way to search downloads for specific version/os.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` is too low-level and might cause broken packages in certain situations. A more reliable approach is to use `apt` in the following fashion (after downloading the `.deb` from https://www.google.com/chrome/?platform=linux):

```bash
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

<sup>Note the `./` prefix — without it apt will attempt to parse the parameter as the name of a package in the apt repos rather than a local file.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just download the .deb file from Chrome's website and install it later, like you do in windows.